# Apache nifi Invoke Http with url containing %2F

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using Apache nifi invokeHttp processor to call [Google API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#rest-download-object). The url contains a path which i need to encode.So in the URL,only path is encoded e.g. `resources%2F8cb90ae6-16cc-4460-99f4-3ae0689b3b66%2Fdata_asset%2FCETIvowels-38.pdf`

However whenver I set encoded url, the processor internally replaces %2F with %252F which results in HTTP 404 response.

E.g. Nifi convert URL - `https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/t-bis-1hg-jk/o/resources%2F8cb90ae6-16cc-4460-99f4-3ae0689b3b66%2Fdata_asset%2FCETIvowels-38.pdf?alt=media`
to `https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/t-bis-1hg-jk/o/resources%252F8cb90ae6-16cc-4460-99f4-3ae0689b3b66%252Fdata_asset%252FCETIvowels-38.pdf?alt=media`

Comment: You're encoding it twice. Solution: don't.

Comment: @user207421 i am not encoding it twice, I am encoding `resources/8cb90ae6-16cc-4460-99f4-3ae0689b3b66/data_asset/CETIvowels-38.pdf` only. And that too only once before giving complete URL to invokeHTTP processor